# C# Namespace not found for DLL

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli, wrapper

Ok, I will preface this by saying I did do a look up and read a lot of similar questions and answers on here before posting this.

Background Info
Using Visual Studio Professional 2013

Goal:
This project is for my own amusement and to try to learn as much as I can.

I have a native C++ header file called BinaryTree.h which is just a simple data structure that uses recursive logic to build a binary search tree. It works quite well on its own.

I want to build a GUI in C# that uses this. (Its not really useful or practical, I just choose it, well because I wanted to. Also, while the logic inside the binary tree class is complex(ish), I only need to call 2 methods, a addNode method, and a toString method which return the max depth and number of nodes).

I choose using a c++/cli wrapper to accomplish this. Everything seemed to go well, the build was successful and a .dll file was created in the debug directory of my project.

Now, I started in on the C# side of things. I added the .dll file to references. However, when I typed in " using filename.dll;" I got an error saying "Type or namespace not found...".

To reiterate I did some researching. I found (it seemed in VS2010) that different target frameworks could cause this error. I checked mine, targets for both were net4.5, so that is not the problem.

Here is the code from my c++/cli wrapper. Perhaps it has something to do with using templates? Any help is appreciated.

```
#pragma once

#include "D:\Schoolwork 2015\Test Projects\CPPtoC#WrapperTest\CPPLogic\CPPLogic\BinaryTree.h"

using namespace System;

namespace BinaryTreeWrapper {

    template<class Data>
    public ref class BinaryTreeWrapperClass
    {
    public:
        BinaryTreeWrapperClass(){ tree = new BinaryTree(); }
        ~BinaryTreeWrapperClass(){ this->!BinaryTreeWrapperClass(); }
        !BinaryTreeWrapperClass(){ delete tree; }

        //methods
        void wrapperAddNode(Data)
        {
            tree->addNode(Data);
        }
        std::string wrapperToString()
        {
            return tree->toString();
        }

    private:
        BinaryTree* tree;
    };
}
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image: Error]

**EDIT**
Ok, so here is a weird thing... my original file built just fine with the new code and produced a .dll file. However, I decided to try a fresh project since the namespace was still not being found. Upon moving the code over and trying to build, I've run into 4 errors:

Error   1   error C2955: 'BinaryTree' : use of class template requires template argument list

Error   2   error C2512: 'BinaryTree' : no appropriate default constructor available

Error   3   error C2662: 'void BinaryTree::addNode(Data)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'BinaryTree' to 'BinaryTree &'

Error   4   error C2662: 'std::string BinaryTree::toString(void) const' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'BinaryTree' to 'const BinaryTree &'

I copied the code exactly, only changing the namespace to "TreeWrapper' and the class name to 'TreeWrapperClass'.

To help, I've include a snippet from my BinaryTree.h file. There is a bunch more that defines the 'NODE' class, but I didn't want to clutter it up more than i needed.

After further investigation, it appears the problem lies with using 'generic'. If I switch it all to 'template' it builds just fine, but then it can't be used as a reference in C# (getting the namespace error). I built a test project using very simple methods (no templates) and was able to use the .dll wrapper I made in C#. So the problem lies with templates and generics.

**Last Edit**
I've found if I change the code to initiate the template as 'int' it works just fine, and I can use it in C#. For example:

```
...
BinaryTreeWrapperClass(){ tree = new BinaryTree<int>(); }
....
private:
BinaryTree<int>* tree;
```

BinaryTree.h

```
template<class Data>
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    Node<Data>* root;
    unsigned int nNodes;
    unsigned int maxDepth;
    unsigned int currentDepth;
    void traverse(Node<Data>*& node, Data data);
public:
    BinaryTree();
    ~BinaryTree();
    void addNode(Data);
    std::string toString() const 
    {
        std::stringstream sstrm;
        sstrm << "\n\t"
            << "Max Depth:       " << maxDepth << "\n"
            << "Number of Nodes: " << nNodes << "\n";
        return sstrm.str(); // convert the stringstream to a string
    }

};

template<class Data>
BinaryTree<Data>::BinaryTree() //constructor
{
    //this->root = NULL;
    this->root = new Node<Data>();      //we want root to point to a null node.
    maxDepth = 0;
    nNodes = 0;
}

template<class Data>
BinaryTree<Data>::~BinaryTree() //destructor
{

}

template<class Data>
void BinaryTree<Data>::addNode(Data data)
{
    traverse(root, data);   //call traverse to get to the node
    //set currentDepth to 0
    currentDepth = 0;
}

template<class Data>
void BinaryTree<Data>::traverse(Node<Data>*& node, Data data)
{
    //increment current depth
    currentDepth++;

    if (node == NULL)       //adds new node with data
    {
        node = new Node<Data>(data);
        //increment nNode
        nNodes++;
        //increment maxDepth if current depth is greater
        if (maxDepth < currentDepth)
        {
            maxDepth = currentDepth - 1;        //currentDepth counts root as 1, even though its 0;
        }
        return;
    }

    else if (node->getData() >= data)       //case for left, getData must be bigger. The rule is, if a number is equal to getData or greater, it is added to the left node
    {
        Node<Data>* temp = node->getLeftNode();
        traverse(temp, data);               //recursive call, going down left side of tree
        node->setLeftNode(temp);
    }
    else if (node->getData() < data)        //case for right, getData must be less
    {
        Node<Data>* temp = node->getRightNode();
        traverse(temp, data);
        node->setRightNode(temp);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I created an empty class library project and compiled it then imported into a C# project and couldn't duplicate this issue. Visual Studio saw the new namespace immediately. I would suggest running through the build options and make sure `Common Language Runtime Support` is set to `/clr`

Comment: That is very strange. I check to make sure that option is set to /clr and it is.
I also tried creating a new library project as well, with the same issue.

Comment: @ahwm that's not the problem here (I'll write an answer to explain what's wrong with this code)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I admit I'm not too familiar with C++. I've done a little bit but C# is what I work with day in and day out. I took a stab at it to see if I could see anything. :)

Comment: @ahwm well... C++/CLI is tricky :-) It allows you to mix native and managed code and it can quickly become confusing because of that. It's pretty good for interop scenarios though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a `template`, but are not actually instantiating it. C++/CLI templates are just like C++ templates - if you don't instantiate them, they just don't exist outside of the compilation unit.

You're looking for *generics* here (yes, C++/CLI has *both* templates and generics). And here's how you declare a generic in C++/CLI:

```
generic<class Data>
public ref class BinaryTreeWrapperClass
{
    // ...
}
```

But you'll get stuck at this point for several reasons.

First, I'll include the parts which are OK:

```
generic<class Data>
public ref class BinaryTreeWrapperClass
{
public:
    BinaryTreeWrapperClass(){ tree = new BinaryTree(); }
    ~BinaryTreeWrapperClass(){ this->!BinaryTreeWrapperClass(); }
    !BinaryTreeWrapperClass(){ delete tree; }

private:
    BinaryTree* tree;
};
```

You've got this right.

Next, let's look at:

```
std::string wrapperToString()
{
    return tree->toString();
}
```

That's no good, since you're returning an `std::string` - you don't want to use that from C#, so let's return a `System::String^` instead (using [`marshal_as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)):

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
```

```
System::String^ wrapperToString()
{
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(tree->toString());
}
```

Here, that's much better for use in C#.

And finally, there's this:

```
void wrapperAddNode(Data)
{
    tree->addNode(Data);
}
```

See... here you'll have to do some *real* interop. You want to pass a managed object to a native one for storage. The GC will get in your way.

The GC is allowed to *relocate* any managed object (move it to another memory location), but your native code is clueless about this. You'll need to *pin* the object so that the GC won't move it.

There are several ways to do this, and I don't know what `BinaryTree::addNode` looks like, but I'll just suppose it's `BinaryTree::addNode(void*)`.

For long-term object pinning, you can use a [`GCHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx).

The full code looks like this:

```
generic<class Data>
public ref class BinaryTreeWrapperClass
{
public:
    BinaryTreeWrapperClass()
    {
        tree = new BinaryTree();
        nodeHandles = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle>();
    }

    ~BinaryTreeWrapperClass(){ this->!BinaryTreeWrapperClass(); }

    !BinaryTreeWrapperClass()
    {
        delete tree;
        for each (auto handle in nodeHandles)
            handle.Free();
    }

    void wrapperAddNode(Data data)
    {
        auto handle = System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::Alloc(
            safe_cast<System::Object^>(data),
            System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandleType::Pinned);
        nodeHandles->Add(handle);
        tree->addNode(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer());
    }

    System::String^ wrapperToString()
    {
        return msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(tree->toString());
    }

private:
    BinaryTree* tree;
    System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle>^ nodeHandles;
};
```

This allocates a `GCHandle` for each node, and stores it in a list in order to free it later. Freeing a *pinned* handle releases a reference to the object (so it becomes collectable if nothing else references it) as well as its pinned status.

Comment: Thanks so much. The System::String^ makes a lot of sense, I can't believe I forgot about it. I'm not familiar with cli at all and it just slipped my mind. 

The GCHandle also makes a lot of sense. I didn't think about having to pin it so the native class will know where it is.

The 'auto' keyword is similar to "var" in native c++ correct?

Again, thankyou for the in depth and informative answer.

Comment: Is there a particular syntax to use the generated .dll in my C# program? I am still getting "Type or Namespace not found". I am using the syntax "Using BinaryTreeWrapper;". It is both the name of the .dll and of the namespace. Could that be causing a conflict?

Comment: In C++ (and C++/CLI), `auto` is the same as `var` in C#. And there's no particular syntax to use the dll, it should work if you set up your reference correctly. You could also try to set the C# project platform to the same as the C++/CLI project.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around I think I found the answer, although not definitively, so if anyone can chime in I would appreciate it. (Apologies in advance for any misuse of vocabulary, but I think I can get the idea across).

It seems the problem lies in the fundamental difference between templates in native C++ and generics. Templates are instantiated at compilation, and are considered a type. They cannot be changed at runtime, whereas generics can. I don't think there is an elegant way to solve that.

At least I accomplished one goal of my project, which was learning as much as I can haha. I was able to get c++/cli wrappers working for things without templates, and if I choose a type for the template before building the .dll (see above)

If anyone else has an idea please let me know.